# How do I arrange 20 Buttons in a format of 5 rows and 4 columns in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

My situation is like this

I have a background image and 20 characters written on it

I placed 1 invisible button on each of 20 characters so that when the user clicks the the character he actually clicks the button and an audio of that character starts.

But here is the main problem----If I change the emulator or my mobile to landscape mode or choose a tablet or choose a different emulator like Nexus 4,Nexus 5 for testing, the buttons are moved from their places(Meaning they are no longer on the exact character).

I want those buttons to remain on that part of the image only

I could use Grid Layout but I don't know how to use it.I am still learning android

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/sv2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/rl2"
    android:background="@drawable/f1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="91dp"
        android:layout_height="91dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="playAlif"
        android:layout_marginTop="278dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="99dp"
        android:onClick="playBaa"
        android:background="@null"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:onClick="playTaa"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
        android:id="@+id/button3" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:onClick="playThaa"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
        android:id="@+id/button5" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="99dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:onClick="playJeem"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
        android:id="@+id/button4" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="99dp"
        android:onClick="playHaa"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        android:id="@+id/button6" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="93dp"
        android:onClick="playKhaa"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
        android:id="@+id/button8" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="89dp"
        android:layout_height="89dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="playDaal"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button4"
        android:id="@+id/button7" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="84dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
        android:onClick="playDhaal"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button7"
        android:background="@null"
        android:id="@+id/button10" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="84dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="playRaa"
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button4" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:onClick="playZaa"
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button9" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="89dp"
        android:layout_height="89dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="playSeen"
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button10" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="89dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:onClick="playSheen"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button10"
        android:id="@+id/button13" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:onClick="playSaad"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
        android:id="@+id/button16" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:onClick="playDhaad"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button12"
        android:id="@+id/button14" />



    <Button
        android:layout_width="89dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="playTaaa"
        android:id="@+id/button15"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:onClick="playZhaa"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button13"
        android:id="@+id/button18" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="82dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button18"
        android:onClick="playAeen"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button18"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button13"
        android:id="@+id/button17" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="playGhaeen"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button14"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button14"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button17"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button16" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:onClick="playDua"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
        android:id="@+id/button38" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="playBismillah"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button38"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button3"
        android:onClick="playDua"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/button70" />


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/n"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button5"
        android:onClick="next"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button8"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/b"
        android:onClick="back"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button70"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button38"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button38"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3" />


</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

```js
package com.example.furqanhussain.nooraniqaida;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by Furqan Hussain on 23-Jan-16.
 */
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer mp;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.page1);

    }
    public void playAlif(View v){

        mp= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alif);
        mp.start();
    }

    public void playBaa(View v){
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.baa);
        mp.start();
    }

    public void playTaa(View v){
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.taa);
        mp.start();
    }

    public void playThaa(View v){
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.thaa);
        mp.start();
    }

    public void playJeem(View v){
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.jeem);
        mp.start();
    }

    public void playHaa(View v){
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.haa);
        mp.start();
    }

    public void playKhaa(View v){
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.khaa);
        mp.start();
    }

    public void playDaal(View v){
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.daal);
        mp.start();
    }

    public void playDhaal(View v){
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.dhaal);
        mp.start();
    }

    public void playRaa(View v){
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.raa);
        mp.start();
    }

    public void playZaa(View v){
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.zaa);
        mp.start();
    }

    public void playSeen(View v){
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.seen);
        mp.start();
    }

    public void playSheen(View v){
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.sheen);
        mp.start();
    }

    public void playSaad(View v){
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.saad);
        mp.start();

    }

    public void playDhaad(View v){
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.dhaad);
        mp.start();
    }

    public void playTaaa(View v){
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.taaa);
        mp.start();
    }

    public void playZhaa(View v){
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.zhaa);
        mp.start();
    }

    public void playAeen(View v){
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.aeen);
        mp.start();
    }

    public void playGhaeen(View v){
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.ghaeen);
        mp.start();
    }

    public void playBismillah(View v){
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.bismillah);
        mp.start();

    }

    public void playDua(View v){
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.dua);
        mp.start();
    }

    public void back(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void next(View v){
        Intent i =new Intent(this,ThirdActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }


}
```

Comment: post your code as concisely as you can, including any XML

Answer (score 0):

You need to create separate views for portrait and landscape mode and when you rotate phone your buttons should be in same place, something like this but this is only for landscape mode:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/sunce_duga"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <LinearLayout        
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="5" >

        <ImageView
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/A"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/pressed"
            android:contentDescription="@null" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/B"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/pb"
            android:contentDescription="@null" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/V"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/pv"
            android:contentDescription="@null" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/G"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/pg"
            android:contentDescription="@null" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/D"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/pd"
            android:contentDescription="@null" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="5" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/DJ"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/pdj"
            android:contentDescription="@null" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/E"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/pe"
            android:contentDescription="@null" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ZH"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/pzh"
            android:contentDescription="@null" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Z"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/pz"
            android:contentDescription="@null" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/I"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/pi"
            android:contentDescription="@null" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Also, your MediaPlayer needs to be to released, you need

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mmp) {

mmp.release();
}
});
```

inside of OnClickListener() method.
Find tutorials on web and learn about layouts. We will help you when you are stuck but real work you will need to do.

Answer (score -1):

Just populate your Gridlayout using a nested for loop.

```
for(int rows = 0; rows < 5; rows++){
    for(int columns = 0; columns < 4; columns++){
        Button myButton = new Button();
        myButton.setText(row * column);
        myGridLayout.add(myButton);
    }
}
```